# Get PHP array values and print it on different columns

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multiple-columns

Here I have a loop containing 5 names in a `<table>` row. This `table` should be a ranking where the first column will display a row of the participant names and the other 10 columns should display the scores.

For the empty columns where I want to add the score numbers, I'd like to create an `array` for each participant and make it loop through the `<td>`. Into the `array` there are 10 numbers where each number should display on each empty `<td>` left.

```
//Names
$names = array("Mike", "Kyle", "Johnny", "Will", "Vasques");

//scores values for each name
$scores = array(
    "Mike"    => array(04, 03, 00, 07, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Kyle"    => array(07, 01, 00, 03, 04, 01, 00, 07, 03, 04, 04),
    "Johnny"  => array(07, 07, 00, 03, 00, 04, 00, 01, 01, 04, 03),
    "Will"    => array(03, 04, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Vasques" => array(03, 01, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 07)
);

//start loop for rows
for($x=0; $x<count($names); $x++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  //column for the names
  echo "<td>$names[$x]</td>";
  //loop for columns where the score should be displayed
  for($td=2; $td<=10; $td++) {
    echo "<td></td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

It should display something like this:

```
Mike   04  03  00  07  04  07  00  01  00  07  04
Kyle   07  01  00  03  04  01  00  07  03  04  04
Johnny 03  01  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  07
```

and so on...

Comment: would you not just replace echo "<td></td>"; with echo "<td>{$scores[$names[$x]][$td - 2]}</td>"

Comment: do you need to cross validate `$names` with `$scores`?, or just simply print out the `$scores` on the table? a simple foreach  should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($scores as $key=>$value)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>$key</td>";
     for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) 
     {
         echo "<td>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
     }
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Example full code view**

```
    <?php
//Names
$names = array("Mike", "Kyle", "Johnny", "Will", "Vasques");

//scores values for each name
$scores = array(
    "Mike"    => array(04, 03, 00, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 07, 04),
    "Kyle"    => array(07, 01, 00, 03, 04, 01, 00, 07, 03, 04, 04),
    "Johnny"  => array(07, 07, 00, 03, 00, 04, 00, 01, 01, 04, 03),
    "Will"    => array(03, 04, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 04),
    "Vasques" => array(03, 01, 00, 03, 04, 07, 00, 01, 00, 07, 07)
);
echo "<table>";
foreach($scores as $key=>$value)
{
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>$key</td>";
     for($x=0; $x<count($value); $x++) 
     {
          if (is_numeric($value[$x])) 
     {
        echo "<td>".sprintf('%02d', $value[$x])."</td>";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<td>". $value[$x]."</td>";
     }
     }
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Output

```
Mike    04  03  00  -   -   -   -   -   -   07  04
Kyle    07  01  00  03  04  01  00  07  03  04  04
Johnny  07  07  00  03  00  04  00  01  01  04  03
Will    03  04  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  04
Vasques 03  01  00  03  04  07  00  01  00  07  07
```

Comment: That works fine and you even remember to output the extra 0 before the numbers! That was awesome!

Comment: Just one more question. I never knew the `sprintf` property before. I noticed that it outputs an extra 0 for the numbers. But I noticed that it convert single values to zero. Is that possible keep fields that has a single dash like "-" instead converting it to zero??

Comment: @Caio Ferrari Sorry i don't understand your requirement. explain clearly

Comment: For instance: my full table ranking contain some empty values (this is a World Cup ranking and some games that didn't take place are empty). These empty field are filled by a single dash ("-"). Since I added the `sprintf` property, the "-" where converted to 0!

`"Mike" => array(04, 03, 00, "-", "-", "-", "-", "-")`

Gotcha??

Comment: That was awesome! I will learn more about the `sprintf`! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `$names` array, you can just output it as the first level array key. Here's an example using `foreach()` instead of numeric `for()` loops for cleaner code:

```
foreach($scores as $name => $values) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $name . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($values as $val) {
      echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($names as $names)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$names</td>";
   foreach($scores[$names] as $nmscore)
   {
        echo "<td>$nmscore</td>";

   }
echo "</tr>";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($names as $name)
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>$name</td>";
   foreach($scores[$name] as $nmscore)
   {
        echo "<td>$nmscore</td>";

   }
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might want to include an explanation of what this code is doing for the OP.